# Is that possible to connect two phones with adb connect?

Tags: android, adb

I have a question about adb connection. In my case, I create a wifi hotpot in phone A, the phone B connect to this wifi and have a ip address. I want to establish a adb connection in phone A. But i  encounter a error. In my Phone A, I tried below command: stop adbd, start adbd, adb tcpip 5555, adb connec x.x.x.x. It always fails and report: 
unable to connect x.x.x.x. From shell windows, I can find the port-5038 is listenning. ping from phone A is ok too. But it can not work and i don't know how to do it. Anyone can help me about it. Anyone has similar experience?
thanks very much.

Comment: Do you want to establish two adb session using PC or phone A to phone B??

Comment: I just establish one adb session between phone A and Phone B. Starting from Phone A to phone B. Phone A work as a wifi access point, Phone B access it and have a ip address. I want to connect to this ip with adb connect x.x.x.x. So i can use adb command to install my apk. Any idea about this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Please follow steps below:

1. Start wifi hotspot of Phone A
2. Connect Phone B by starting wifi
3. Connect Phone A to PC
4. Run `adb tcpip 5555`
5. Disconnect Phone A from PC
6. Connect Phone B  to PC
7. Run `adb shell`
8. Run `adb connect "PhoneA's IP" 5555`
9. execute `adb shell`

NOTE: If your phoneA is listening on 5555 port and you again start tcpip 5555 then PhoneB have problem to connect with PhoneA with 5555 port,I have encountered problem which you have by enabling tcpip 5555 session in phoneA

Comment: hi, Rahul R Dhobi, thank your answer firstly. I don't understand your step very clearly. your step just like below:1）Start wifi hotspot of Phone A，
2）Connect Phone B by starting wifi，
3）Connect Phone A to PC， Run adb tcpip 5555 Disconnect Phone A from PC
4）Connect Phone B to PC Run adb shell Run adb connect "PhoneA's IP" 5555 execute adb shell.

Comment: Which step you dont understand?

Comment: I just do it again. 1)Connect Phone B with pc, run "adb tcpip 5555", 2)then run "adb connect x.x.x." in phone A, connection can establish. That is cool. Hi, Rahui R Dhobi, Do you know how can I skip "adb tcpip 5555". You know, Phone B is a phone of my customer, i cannot run adb  command in it. Can I connect Phone A and PHone B with a usb cable and run "adb tcpip" in phone A? thanks your help very much.